# How can I extract bbox of polygon geometries in a shapefile using geotools

Tags: shapefile, geotools, bbox

I have a shapefile which has building footprints as polygon features. I want to read shapefile and extract these bbox of these polygon features using geotools. So far I read shapefile but I don't know how can I access geometry and attributes of a shapefile records using geotools. Here is my code; but I don't know how can I do the rest of work for my purpose.

```
package org.geotools;

import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Tiler {
File file = new File ("C:/Users/Ziya/Desktop/Kasustu/footprints.shp");
Map<String, URL> map = new HashMap<String, URL>();
public Tiler() throws IOException {
    map.put("url", file.toURI().toURL());
}

    DataStore dataStore= DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = 
    dataStore.getFeatureSource(dataStore.getTypeNames()[0]);
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a `SimpleFeatureCollection` it is just a case of iterating through the collection and looking at whichever attributes you need. The [`SimpleFeature`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/opengis/src/main/java/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeature.java) interface is well [documented](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/feature/simple/SimpleFeature.html).

```
try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = (SimpleFeatureIterator) inputFeatureCollection.features()) {
  while (itr.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
    //Default geometery 
    Geometry g = (Geometry)f.getDefaultGeomerty();
    //bounding box
    Geometry envPoly = g.getEnvelope(); // a polygon
    Envelope env = geom.getEnvelopeInternal(); // a simple envelope
    double minx = env.getMinX();
    double miny = env.getMinY();
    double maxx = env.getMaxX();
    double maxy = env.getMaxY();

    //access properties or attributes
    Property p = f.getProperty("name");
    PropertyType type = p.getType();
    Name name = p.getName();
    Object v = p.getValue();
    List<Object> l = f.getAttributes();
    Object a1 = f.getAttribute("name");
    Object a2 = f.getAttribute(0);
  }
}
```

Also please use `URLs.fileToUrl(inFile)` instead of `file.toURI().toURL()` your windows users will thank you for it.

Comment: Sorry for dummy question but I come from python and both java and geotools are new world for me. How can I access coordinates of envelope. For example I want to create an array which consist of envelope coordinates for every feature??

Comment: see the update - the real question is why do you want to this?

Comment: I want to exract coordinates of envelopes for every feaute because using them I will construct a rtree data structure. A rtree java implementation requires bounding boxes and their coordinates for rtree construction. Here is the link : https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree. These min and max coordinates are for only an envelope of they are as a list or array of every features envelop coordinates?

Comment: did you look at SpatialIndexFeatureCollection?

Comment: Yes but i did'nt solve my problem. My final purpose is using RTree generating tiles for my data (input shapefile). I need all envelopes and their coordinates for non leaf child nodes and actual polygon features. So it seems SpatialIndexFeatureCollection doesn't return coordinates of non leaf child nodes. Am I wrong?

Comment: but it builds an rtree for you, so you don't need to

Comment: I need to, because using these coordinates I have to generate a jon file which contains leaf and non leaf nodes of the tree and their coordinates for my application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73742/discussion-between-user51044-and-ian-turton).

Comment: It throws an error " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com. vividsolutions. jts. geom.MultiPolygon cannot be cast to org.opengis.geometry.Geometry"  how can I fix this?? @Ian Turton

Comment: Change your import of geometry to the one from jts